# Calculating upwards drift velocity of hydrogen in air, where is the error in my calculations?

Tags: velocity, gas, diffusion, lift

I have the following problem: I'm charging a lead-acid battery in a
container. The charger could fail, producing too many amperes at too many
volts. Too many amperes I can easily handle in a fuse, so I need to handle
too many volts otherwise. The problem is that too high voltage creates perfect conditions
for electrolysis of water into hydrogen and oxygen, which could create an
explosive mixture. Because I know the charger outputs at most 2.5 amperes (if
it outputs more the fuse will burn), I know the maximum possible rate of hydrogen production.

Hydrogen being a lighter gas than air, I plan to drill few large holes into the
top of the container to allow hydrogen to escape. I want to ensure the amount
and size of holes is adequate, so I have to calculate how quickly hydrogen
moves upwards in an atmosphere of air.

Since Faraday's constant is $96500 \frac{\mathrm{As}}{\mathrm{mol}}$, and one hydrogen molecule requires
two electrons, and one hydrogen mol weighs $2.0157\ \mathrm{g}$, I know that $2.5\ \mathrm{A}$ creates

$$\frac{2.5\ \mathrm{A}}{2 \cdot 96500\ \frac{\mathrm{As}}{\mathrm{mol}}} \cdot 2.0157\ \frac{\mathrm{g}}{\mathrm{mol}} = 26\ \frac{\mathrm{µg}}{\mathrm{s}}$$

(Oops, I just noticed that one cell creates this amount, if I have a battery with many cells I need to multiply by the cell count. But this doesn't change the order of magnitude much.)

At all times,
the amount of hydrogen in the container needs to be below the lower explosive
limit of 4%, so I need to ensure hydrogen escapes at least at this rate of $26\ \frac{\mathrm{µg}}{\mathrm{s}}$, if the concentration is 4%, preferably at a far greater rate.

I also know one cubic meter of hydrogen weighs $0.82\ \mathrm{N}$ and has a lift of $11.81\
\mathrm{N}$, with a net upwards force of $10.99\ \mathrm{N}$. 1 mol of hydrogen is 22.4 liters, so
one mole has a net upwards force of $0.246\ \mathrm{N}$, and one molecule has a net upwards
force of

$$ \frac{0.246\ \mathrm{N}}{6.022\cdot10^{23}} = 4.09\cdot10^{-25}\ \mathrm{N} $$

So I need to know the drift velocity of a hydrogen molecule with a net upwards
force of $4.09\cdot10^{-25}\ \mathrm{N}$.

Fortunately, I can estimate the diffusion constant of hydrogen using formula
from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_diffusivity and I got an estimate of
$0.6\cdot10^{-4} \frac{\mathrm{m}^2}{\mathrm{s}}$. This is somewhat larger than typical range (according to
https://www.comsol.com/multiphysics/diffusion-coefficient "A typical diffusion
coefficient for a molecule in the gas phase is in the range of $10^{-6} \frac{\mathrm{m}^2}{\mathrm{s}}$ to $10^{-5} \frac{\mathrm{m}^2}{\mathrm{s}}$"), but then again hydrogen is a very small molecule.

So using [Einstein relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_relation_(kinetic_theory)), I obtain the mobility of

$$µ = \frac{D}{kT} = \frac{0.6\cdot10^{-4} \frac{\mathrm{m}^2}{\mathrm{s}}}{1.380649 \cdot 10^{-23} \frac{\mathrm{J}}{\mathrm{K}} \cdot 293.15\ \mathrm{K}} = 1.5\cdot10^{16} \frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{Ns}}$$

Then I get the drift velocity: $4.09\cdot10^{-25}\ \mathrm{N} \cdot 1.5\cdot10^{16} \frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{Ns}} = 6\cdot10^{-9}\ \frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}}$ which
seems far too small to me, so this is showing I probably have already
calculated something incorrectly at this point.

The battery container has size of 0.35 m x 0.33 m and I need to calculate how
many holes of a certain size I need to drill into it to allow hydrogen to
escape. Let's assume at this point that the container is open at the top, so it
would be all holes and no material at all. Gas is escaping at a rate of

$$6\cdot10^{-9}\ \frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}} \cdot 0.35\ \mathrm{m} \cdot 0.33\ \mathrm{m} = 7\cdot10^{-10}\ \frac{\mathrm{m}^3}{\mathrm{s}}$$

and at 4% hydrogen content that's about
$3\cdot10^{-11} \frac{\mathrm{m}^3}{\mathrm{s}}$ of hydrogen. One mole takes 22.4 liters, so that's about $1\cdot10^{-9}\ \frac{\mathrm{mol}}{\mathrm{s}}$
or about $2\ \frac{\mathrm{ng}}{\mathrm{s}}$.

So hydrogen is created at a rate of 13000 times more than it can escape, if the
container has no top! This does not seem reasonable.

I have also calculated using the same Einstein relation that if I release some
propane in a basement, it will due to diffusion rise quite high, in fact quite
a lot of propane is present even at a height of about 15 kilometers after it
reaches the equilibrium that drift and diffusion at every height is in balance.
This result does not correspond with the generally accepted danger of storing
propane in a basement: it will fill all spaces below the ground, and an
explosive mixture will be present there practically forever.

So I must have calculated something incorrectly. What is the error in my
calculation? And how can I calculate how quickly hydrogen drifts upwards in
air, if I know the concentration (4%) and the net upwards force ($4.09\cdot10^{-25}\ \mathrm{N}$ per
molecule)?

Comment: What you are going into is what I consider the most horrible part of statistical mechanics. I think your conceptualisation is wrong; for example, you are thinking about net forces, but really, what is happening is that there is a statistical steady state whereby the slow net bulk flow is somewhat in terminal velocity situation, i.e. statistically net force cancels out. You should also be computing for a single hole in a container. Your situation is most horrible because the easy problem is for nearly ideal gas, and this seems far from it. There is a lot of literature if you want to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your estimate of a vertical velocity of $\sim 6\times 10^{-9}$ m/s is pretty reasonable for gravity-driven molecular drift, but the buoyancy of hydrogen gas is due to gravitational [convection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection#Terminology), not gravitational drift.  This is much faster, but not quite as fast as some numbers that appear online.

**Gravitational Drift**

By dimensional analysis, or by analogy with results for [electrons in a conductor](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Thermodynamics_and_Statistical_Mechanics/Essential_Graduate_Physics_-_Statistical_Mechanics_(Likharev)/06%3A_Elements_of_Kinetics/6.02%3A_The_Ohm_law_and_the_Drude_formula), we expect the drift velocity for a hydrogen atom in air to be

$$v_\mathrm{drift}=\tau F/m$$

where the average gravitational buoyancy force on the molecule is

$$F=\left(\frac{\rho_{air}}{\rho_{H_2}}-1\right)m_{H_2}g$$

and the mean time between collisions of the hydrogen molecule is

$$\tau = \lambda / \langle v_r \rangle$$

Assuming an ideal gas of spherical molecules, the [mean free path](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/menfre.html) of a hydrogen molecule in air of molecular density $n$ is

$$\lambda = \frac{1}{\pi (r_{H_2}+r_{\mathrm{air}})^2 n}$$

where $r$ is the molecular radius and $n=P/kT$ is the molecular density.  The [mean velocity](https://chem.libretexts.org/Under_Construction/Purgatory/CHM_363%3A_Physical_Chemistry_I/13%3A_Kinetic_Theory_of_Gases/13.02%3A_Collision_Theory) of the hydrogen molecule relative to the air molecules is

$$\langle v_r \rangle = \sqrt{\frac{8 k T}{\pi \mu}}$$

where $\mu=m_{H_2}m_{air}/(m_{H_2}+m_{air})$ is the reduced mass. We can can reasonably approximate air as pure nitrogen, so

$$v_\mathrm{drift}\approx
\frac{kT}{\pi (r_{H_2}+r_{N_2})^2 P}
\sqrt{\frac{\pi m_{H_2}m_{N_2}}{8 k T (m_{H_2}+m_{N_2})}} 
\left(\frac{\rho_{H_2}}{\rho_{H_2}}-1\right)
g
$$

Sticking all the numbers in  for 20°C and 1 atm and using the [Van der Waals radii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_radius), I estimate

$$v_\mathrm{drift}=12\times 10^{-9}\,\mathrm{m/s}$$

This is just twice your value, so confirms your order-of-magnititude estimate for the **drift** velocity of a single hydrogen molecule in static air.  (The value will change depending on the proportions in a hydrogen-air mix and if some of the approximate assumptions are changed - but not by orders of magnitude.)

**Gravitational Convection (Buoyancy)**

For a bubble of hydrogen gas released into air, however, the vertical velocity will be much higher because of the buoyancy force acting on the whole "*[parcel](https://www.noaa.gov/jetstream/upperair/parcel-theory)*" of hydrogen.

For example, the expected [terminal buoyant velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11406/145491) of a $10$ m radius hydrogen parcel in air (with drag coefficient $C_D\sim 0.5$) is

$$v \approx \sqrt{\frac{8 g r}{3 C_D} \left( \frac{\rho_{air} - \rho_{hydrogen}}{\rho_{air}} \right)} = 22\,\mathrm{m/s}= 80\,\mathrm{km/h}$$

The [diffusivity of hydrogen in Air](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/air-diffusion-coefficient-gas-mixture-temperature-d_2010.html) at NTP is $\sim 8\times 10^{-5}\,\mathrm{m^2/s}$, so the diffusion time for this parcel in air would be $>2$ days.
In other words, in the (impossible) absence of turbulence or other mixing, a large hydrogen parcel could rise to the top of the Earth's atmosphere before completely diffusing into the air.

This simple model breaks down, of course, when the parcel is so small that it quickly dissipates by diffusing into the air. For example, the terminal velocity and diffusion time of a small $1$ mm radius hydrogen sphere in air are $0.7\,\mathrm{m/s}$ and $0.2$ s, respectively.

The model also fails for larger plumes, since any reasonably sized buoyant hydrogen plume is initially moving fast enough to form turbulent eddies that entrain air, so as the plume rises it becomes broader, slower, and less dense as the hydrogen concentration falls.  The vertical velocity of buoyant plumes typically falls off as $v\propto(z/d)^{-1/3}$, where $z$ is the height above the opening that releases the gas and $d$ is the size of the opening (e.g. see [Schefer 2008](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijhydene.2008.05.091)).

**Published Buoyant Velocity Values**

There are [many unsourced claims on the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hydrogen%22+%2220+m/s%22+%22rises%22+%22times+lighter+than+air%22) going [back to 2005](https://www1.eere.energy.gov/hydrogenandfuelcells/pdfs/h2_safety_fsheet.pdf) that hydrogen rises at $20$ m/s in air.
This value is clearly too high and could be dangerously misleading if used to estimate how fast hydrogen dissipates.  To have a nominal buoyant velocity of $20\,\mathrm{m/s}$, a hydrogen parcel would have to be almost $20$ m in diameter with a [Reynolds number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number#Sphere_in_a_fluid) $\gtrsim 2\times10^6$, so it would quickly mix with air because of turbulent entrainment.

A few sites [report](https://www.google.com/search?q=hydrogen+rises+%221.2+-+9+m/s%22) that hydrogen has a buoyant velocity 1.2 to 9 m/s in air.  These values can be traced back to a 1981 National Bureau of Standards [Monograph](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/MONO/nbsmonograph168.pdf), and they are just the vertical terminal velocities for spherical hydrogen parcels with radii from $3$ to $150$ cm. (The monograph does not explain why this range was chosen.)

**Hydrogen Safety**

A precise safety assessment of any facility where hydrogen gas may be released should be done by a professional engineer using a computational fluid dynamics simulation that is calibrated on the [large relevant research literature](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=hydrogen+safety+buoyancy&btnG=).  Most codes, however, simply emphasize the importance of venting all high points and specify [minimum ventilation requirements](https://www.cedengineering.com/userfiles/M05-021%20-%20Battery%20Room%20Ventilation%20and%20Safety%20-%20US.pdf) :

- [NFPA 76](https://www.nfpa.org/codes-and-standards/all-codes-and-standards/list-of-codes-and-standards/detail?code=76):  Fan capacity should be 1 CFM per sq.ft. of floor space.
- [NFPA 111](https://www.nfpa.org/codes-and-standards/all-codes-and-standards/list-of-codes-and-standards/detail?code=111): recommends a minimum of 2 air-changes per hour
- [ASHRAE Guideline 21P](https://www.ashrae.org/technical-resources/standards-and-guidelines/titles-purposes-and-scopes): 1 CFM per charging amp, no less than 6 air-changes per hour
- [IS 1332](https://archive.org/details/gov.in.is.12332.1988/page/n6/mode/1up?q=battery): 12 air-changes per hour

Note that if using natural ventilation, there is a risk that buoyancy driven flows can be reversed by wind or if the outside temperature is warmer than inside.  For example, you may want to look at ["Analysis of buoyancy-driven ventilation of hydrogen from buildings"](https://www.nrel.gov/docs/fy07osti/41081.pdf) and ["Buoyancy-Driven Ventilation of Hydrogen From Buildings: Laboratory Test and Model Validation"](https://www.nrel.gov/docs/fy09osti/45804.pdf) from the National Renewable Energy Lab.